# Haskell N-ary tree construction

Tags: haskell, recursion, syntax, tree

I am new in Haskell. I trying to learn implementation of N-ary trees in Haskell. I tried to construct N-ary tree and so I create my own data type

```
      data Tree = Empty | Node Integer [Tree] deriving Show
```

I want to construct my Tree from the list. I want to construct such Tree that going to take List elements one by one . If element is smaller it is going to be subtree of previous element else it going to be sibling.My problem is in the base cases and recursion parts. So I write such a code:

```
      arrin :: [Integer] -> Integer -> Integer {-this function takes an array -}
      arrin (x:xs) i                           {- and indexs and return the element-}  
        | i == 0    = x                    {-of that array which on that index -}
        | otherwise = arrin xs (i-1)  


      listToTree :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Tree
      listToTree _ [] = Empty {-First Input will be zero initially-}
      listToTree 11 _ = Empty {-Lets assume that the lenght of my list is 10-}
      listToTree 0 a = Node ( arrin a 0 ) [listToTree 1 a]
      listToTree num a  {-I need your help in this part what should i do-}
          | arrin a num > arrin a (num+1) = Node ( arrin a num ) [listToTree (num+1) a]
          | otherwise = Node ( arrin a num ) [Empty]
```

Any kind of comments and answers will be appreciated.

Comment: What specifically is the question?  What should the code be doing, what is it currently doing, and how is that different from the expected?

Comment: This code does not take all elements of the list it stopped in first empty list that it come across, I know where is my problem actually what I need is an algorithm . So I cannot create the whole tree

Comment: It's still hard to understand what this function is supposed to do.  Can you give an example input and the desired output along with the actual output?

Comment: Input: listToTree 0 [3,2,9,8,4,5,0,1,6,7]                                 Desired output Node 3 [Node 2 [Empty] , Node 9 [Node 8 [Node 4], Node 5 [Node 0],Node 1 [Empty], Node 6 [Empty] ,Node 7 [Empty]]]                                                           My Output Node 3 [Node 2 [Empty]]

Comment: As i said it stops in first Empty node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does your function take an integer as first argument? Also it is not clear if the tree should end in "Node int []" or "Node int empty". If you are ready to accept [Tree] as output you don't even need empty which would probably only really be necessary for the empty list. In that case, the function could be as follows.

```
listToTree :: [Integer] -> [Tree]
listToTree [] = []
listToTree [x] = [Node x []]
listToTree (x1:x2:xs)
    | x2 < x1 = [Node x1 (listToTree (x2:xs))] -- subtree
    | otherwise = Node x1 [] : listToTree (x2:xs) -- sibling
```